# UPDATE ANGULAR v6 -> v8 : How to fix "ERROR in The loader "datatable.component.css" didn't return a string."

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, dependencies, ngx-datatable

I’m updating the version of my project angular v6 to v8.

But I have this error message in my console :

> ERROR in The loader "foo/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/components/datatable.component.css" didn't return a string.

I find [this issues](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/459) who was closed in an earlier version of mine, So I open a [new issue](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1723).I am currently using "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^15.0.2"

I am running the project with AOT :

```
ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.js
```

Package.json :

```
"dependencies": {

"@angular/animations": "^8.1.1",
"@angular/common": "^8.1.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^8.1.1",
"@angular/core": "^8.1.1",
"@angular/forms": "^8.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^8.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.1.1",
"@angular/router": "^8.1.1",
"@angular/service-worker": "^8.1.1",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts": "^1.0.9",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.0.0",
"@storybook/angular": "^5.1.9",
"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^15.0.2",
"@types/mathjs": "^4.4.3",
"@types/storybook__addon-notes": "^3.3.3",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"core-js": "^2.5.6",
"lodash": "^4.17.10",
"mathjs": "^5.3.0",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"ng-mocks": "^8.0.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
"ngx-chips": "^2.0.2",
"ngx-moment": "^3.3.0",
"ngx-permissions": "^7.0.3",
"ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
"sass": "^1.22.5",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.9.1"
```

},

"devDependencies": {

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.801.1",
"@angular/cli": "~8.1.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.1.1",
"@angular/language-service": "^8.1.1",
"@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
"@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^2.3.4",
"@ngx-rocket/scripts": "^3.0.4",
"@storybook/addon-actions": "^4.1.18",
"@storybook/addon-links": "^4.1.18",
"@storybook/addon-notes": "^5.1.9",
"@storybook/addons": "^4.1.18",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
"@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.2",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.136",
"@types/node": "^8.10.50",
"@types/storybook__addon-actions": "^3.4.3",
"@types/storybook__addon-links": "^3.3.5",
"@types/webpack-env": "^1.14.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
"hads": "^2.0.0",
"htmlhint": "^0.10.3",
"https-proxy-agent": "^2.2.2",
"husky": "^0.14.3",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.0",
"karma": "^4.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
"ng-packagr": "^5.1.0",
"prettier": "^1.18.2",
"pretty-quick": "^1.11.1",
"protractor": "^5.4.2",
"puppeteer": "^1.18.1",
"stylelint": "^10.1.0",
"stylelint-config-prettier": "^5.2.0",
"stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "^3.3.0",
"stylelint-config-standard": "^18.3.0",
"stylelint-scss": "^3.9.1",
"ts-node": "~7.0.1",
"tsickle": "^0.35.0",
"tslint": "~5.11.0",
"tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
"typescript": "^3.4.3"
```

},
}

angular.json :

```
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/apple-touch-icon.png",
          "src/robots.txt",
          "src/manifest.json",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": ["src/main.scss"],
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "serviceWorker": true,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

Furthermore, I also tried to [add a webpack](https://netbasal.com/customize-webpack-configuration-in-your-angular-application-d09683f6bd22) with this config :

```
  rules: [
  {
    test: /\.sass$/,
    include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
    loader: ['css-to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: helpers.root('src', 'app', 'node_module'),
    loader: ['css-to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
  }
```

but that didn't fix anything.

How can I load the file datatable.component.css correclty ?

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue after updating angular7 to 8. It can be resolved by changing the version of `raw-loader` to `1.0.0` in package.json file and run `npm install`.

```
{
    "name": "client-frontend",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --aot",
        "build": "ng build ",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^8.2.7",
        "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "^8.2.7",
        "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.7",
        "@angular/core": "^8.2.7",
        "@angular/forms": "^8.2.7",
        "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/material": "^8.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.7",
        "@angular/router": "^8.2.7",

        "raw-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
        "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
        "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
        "tslint": "~5.20.0",
        "typescript": "3.5.3"
    }
}
```